# How to get MouseX/Y inside a static function?

Tags: actionscript-3

I need Mouse cordinates inside a static function. It isn't a mousevent function and there isn't anything passed in the function.

```
// Main class
MyClass.something();

// MyClass
public static function something():void
{
    // Get Mouse Cordinates
    // myclassclip.x = mouse cordinates
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to set a static ref to the stage before this function gets called, from some init code. Is it timeline in Flash Pro, or something else?

Comment: pass it in as a parameter maybe? public static function something(__x:Number,__y:Number):void

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class MyClass extends Sprite
    {
        private static var _instance:MyClass;

        public function MyClass() 
        {
            super();
        }

        public static function getInstance():MyClass
        {
            if (!_instance)
                _instance = new MyClass();

            return _instance;
        }

        public static function testMouse():Point
        {
            var myStage:Stage = _instance.stage;
            var point:Point = new Point(myStage.mouseX, myStage.mouseY);

            return point;
        }
    }
}
```

In a Main class:

```
// Somewhere in the Main class
addChild(MyClass.getInstance());

// In other place in the Main class
MyClass.testMouse();
```

Comment: So essentially using a static variable to get the stage reference, works :)